# Diff-in-Diff with a binary outcome? (i.e., comparing proportions of two groups over two time points in a paired setting)

Tags: chi-squared-test, difference-in-difference, mcnemar-test

Let's say I have students randomly split into two groups (treatment and control). Each student is given a test and they either pass or fail. They then either take a course (the students in "treatment") or they don't (students in "control") - then they take the exam again. I want to know if the course helped the students who took the exam in the second time.

If we had only the second time, and wanted to compare treatment to control, we could use Chi-square test (or Fisher's exact test).

If we had only one group (e.g., treatment), and we wanted to compare the success in the example before-after the course, we could have used McNemar's test.

But what test would I use to compare the effect of the course on the improvement in the exam's pass rates?

If the outcome wasn't pass/fail, but a normal outcome, we could have taken the difference between the before and after for each student, and then compare the two groups using a two sample $t$-test (i.e., Diff-in-Diff).

But how should I proceed with a binary outcome?

Comment: Do those who "pass" take the exam again? Do they also possibly take the course again if assigned to "treatment"? Is this actually a randomized design?

Comment: It's helpful to think of these models in a regression setting. Why not use covariates equal to (control or treatment) and (pass or not first time) with response (pass or not second time)?

Answer (score 0):

I have no doubt that an appropriate regression model might be more elegant
and might allow for testing more details than can be done with a couple of t tests. However, it seems to me that
the two most important issues are (a) whether the treatment group improved
from the first exam to the second, possibly on account of learning something
in the course. and (b) whether the treatment group improved
more than the control group from the first to the second exam.

If you have about 30 students in each group and the exams have about 50
T-F questions each, then the scores might be nearly normal so that
(a) could be answered with a paired t test (or a one-sample t test on
differences, and (b) could be answered with a two-sample t test.
With such sample sizes and no indications of serious departures from normality,
my first analyses would be to do these two tests
to get an idea whether the major expectations of the study are met.

I have simulated some fake data for purposes of illustration.
Let the improvement scores for treatment and control groups be `td` and `cd`,
respectively.

```
summary(td)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   5.00    7.25   10.00    9.40   11.00   14.00 
summary(cd)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  0.000   3.000   4.000   4.367   5.750   9.000
```

For my fake data, boxplots (Treatment=1) show no serious skewness or outliers.

```
boxplot(td, cd, horizontal=T)
```

[image]

Normal probability plots show discreteness but no serious departures
for normality.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 qqnorm(td,main="Treatment: Normal Probability Plot"); qqline(td)
 qqnorm(cd,main="Control: Normal Probability Plot"); qqline(cd)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

Thus, it seems reasonable to compare 'improvement' scores with a two-sample t test.
The P-value is very nearly $0$ and we reject the null hypothesis (of no difference).

```
t.test(td, cd)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  td and cd
t = 8.5125, df = 57.587, p-value = 9.006e-12
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 3.849569 6.217098
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 9.400000  4.366667
```

Also, a right-sided, one-sample t test on the improvement scores in the treatment group, finds
statistically significant improvement.

```
t.test(td, alt="gr")

        One Sample t-test

data:  td
t = 23.5, df = 29, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true mean is greater than 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 8.720349      Inf
sample estimates:
mean of x 
      9.4
```

---

**Addendum:** In your Question, it seems that you might not have exam scores; just whether subjects passed or failed the exams. What's above
was written hoping you do have scores. But even if not, I suppose you know, whether
a subject improved (went from fail to pass), stayed the same, or went from pass to fail.

Then for Treatment subjects you might have 3 down, 5 same, and 22 up.
You could do a proportion test to see if the proportion who improved
is significantly better than half. With these counts the answer is Yes.
[These hypothetical counts are *not* derived from the simulated data used for the t tests.]

```
prop.test(c(22, 8), c(30,30), alt="gr", cor=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(22, 8) out of c(30, 30)
X-squared = 13.067, df = 1, p-value = 0.0001503
alternative hypothesis: greater
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.2788575 1.0000000
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.7333333 0.2666667
```

By contrast, if the Control group had 4 down, 21 same, 5, improved, then you could do a chi-squared test to see if the Treatment group did significantly
better. The result is that Treatment and Control groups are clearly not homogeneous. (The simulation option was used because the cells for subjects going from pass
to fail have so few counts.)

```
MAT = cbind(c(3, 5, 22), c(4, 21, 5))
chisq.test(MAT, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  MAT
X-squared = 20.693, df = NA, p-value = 0.0004998
```

Fisher's exact test is another option, also with a highly significant result.

```
fisher.test(MAT)

        Fisher's Exact Test for Count Data

data:  MAT
p-value = 1.123e-05
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
```

---

*Note:* The data for t tests were sampled in R according to the program below.

```
set.seed(301)
t1 = rbinom(30, 50, .5)
td = rbinom(30, 50, .2)
t2 = t1 + td
c1 = rbinom(30, 50, .5)
cd = rbinom(30, 50, .1)-1
c2 = c1 + cd
```